# Custom ListPopupWindow rendered in different widths

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using  Android.Support.V7.Widget.ListPopupWindow  as a Drop-Down Menu from a Button within my layout. Here is the code snippet I am using

```
void MenuIcon_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popupWindow = new Android.Support.V7.Widget.ListPopupWindow (this);
    popupAdapter = new MenuPopUpAdapter (this,selectedIndex,menuList);
    popupAdapter.ItemClick+= PopupAdapter_ItemClick;
    popupWindow.SetAdapter (popupAdapter);
    popupWindow.AnchorView = menuButton;
    Display display = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
    Point size = new Point();
    display.GetSize (size);
    int width = size.X;
    popupWindow.Width =160;
    popupWindow.Show ();
}
```

But while debugging I noted that, even though I have given it a static width, it is rendered differently in different devices. What is causing this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the different screen densities in Android devices. You need to mention dimensions in DPs(Density Independent Pixels) to overcome this issue. [This documentation from Google will be a nice read](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

You can get the corresponding pixel value to be mentioned while setting dimensions programatically from this method.

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        int px = (int)Math.Round(dp * (displayMetrics.Density));       
        return px;
    }
```

You may modify the code as above to fix the issue

```
popupWindow.Width =dpToPx(160);
```